# How to add small 220 Volt Heater from an existing 220V 30 Amp receptacle

Tags: electrical, electric-heat

I recently upgraded my laundry room from an electric dryer to a gas dryer. The 30 amp circuit was left in place including the receptacle for for the dryer, which was very handy for the floor refinisher to just plug in to. Now that it is getting colder I would like to add a small electric baseboard heater and thermostat to keep the room warmer. I would like to tap the existing 30 amp circuit (my service box is full even if I didn't mind pulling the extra cable) for the heater, possibly by just running a 30 amp plug from the thermostat into the outlet.

Comment: Pictures would help.  The best answer you can get from what's written here now is convert the outlet (is it surface mount or recessed?) to feed surface raceway to feed the thermostat and baseboard heat.  Your heat may not require a 30 amps, if so you can downsize the breaker, so that your wiring extension can also be downsized.

Comment: Interesting question, and this came up last week.  **Can you put a 240V/30A plug on a piece of equipment that actually draws little enough to be suitable for a 20A or 15A receptacle?**  (20A is max 3840W continuous, 15A is max 2880W continuous).

Comment: Tyson -- I desire to keep the 30 amp outlet available.

Comment: Harper -- this is exactly what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: A picture is worth a 1000-words.

Comment: Paul Logan -- There is a 30AMP socket formerly from a dryer. I wish to tap or plugin to that socket to power a 2 AMP 220V heater with an inexpensive thermostat in the middle. If it were practical I would wire a separate 15 amp 220 circuit with 14 guage wire. All the parts involved can be viewed online at any major hardware retailer's site. If there were a short in the 14 guage wiring run the 30 amp breaker might not trip before a fire started. I'm looking for an easy and safe solution to implement the heater with that outlet as my start point.

Comment: Can you locate a sub-breaker box on the wall near the outlet? You could supply the box with a 30 amp plug and cord. Put the right breaker(s) into the sub and run the right-sized wire to the heaters.

Comment: Dave McGinty please propose that as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to tackle this issue is to remove the 30 amp plug and replace it with a junction box. Locate a sub-breaker box on the wall and feed it with 10-ga 2-wire +ground cable from the new junction box. With the sub-box you can create two or 3 circuits with different amp loads (15, 20, 30) and wire sizes. Be sure to enclose the feed and any load cables in conduit if they are exposed to the living area.  And follow all safety rules, including shutting off the breaker at the main box while the work is ongoing.

Comment: I'm going with your earlier comment which is to use a 30amp appliance plug to feed the new subpanel. In those rare instances  30 amps is needed the other load should be removed from it anyway. If for some reason the laundry were reverted to using an electric dryer again, the need to disconnect the heater would force a review of the circuit.